# Bootstrap included with Parse Starter Project Swift, how do I remove it?

Tags: xcode, swift

So I've downloaded the Parse Starter Project from [Parse GitHub](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) but I've noticed a difference between this Xcode project and the one on the official Parse site and that is that Bootstrap is included with this project file somehow.

Now it might be a huge problem but it is somewhat annoying as the inclusion of Bootstrap is generating some errors whenever I build the project, as demonstrated in [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq6k0vkub2hg7p7/Screenshot%202016-04-14%2016.34.55.png?dl=0).

Being somewhat new to Xcode, and development altogether, I have not quite figured out how to remove all references to Bootstrap from this project.

It is not visible as a framework, like Parse is, in the directory view which shows me all the project files and it is not imported into AppDelegate.swift or ViewController.swift either.

It did find a reference to it in the Build Phases settings, where it is added within the Target Dependencies, but removing it from there does not get rid of the error messages for me.

Comment: Why download Parse from github then instead of the one on the official parse site? Is the one on github offering additional features that the original one featured on the parse website is not offering?

Comment: Good question, I've noticed that the GitHub Parse starter files are more frequently maintained than the ones on the official site, for instance there seems to be something missing from the official Parse files if you want to configure Push Notifications, however Push works fine if you download the GitHub versions.

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing i can tell you is that there's a framework called Bolts that Bootstrap is dependent on and it can't find it. I don't know how to fix the issue on account it's unique to something i'm not accustomed to :3 Maybe the github has a discussion forum where people are posting similar issues?

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can find the answers there.